# How to group plot colors in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, graph

I have a plot in R using `ggplot`, say like the following. How can I group the plot colors, like all **Control** having same color, and the **Treated** having another color? So basically only two different colors total. Probably I need to use group aesthetics to do this.

[Here](https://file.io/wYZnQCSCpZCw) is the data file. Here is the code:

```
{r}
growth_data_long <- growth_data %>% pivot_longer(-`animal`, 
                                   names_to=("Day"),
                                   values_to=("Growth"))

growth_data_long
{r}
growth_data_long %>% ggplot(aes(Day,Growth, group= animal)) + aes(color=animal) +geom_line()+
  geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide sample of your data using `dput`.  Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Added the data file.

Comment: Have you tried changing `color=animal` to `color=group_name` where `group_name` is whatever you call the Control and Treated groups?

Comment: @Tjn25 no what is this? Please share the answer!

Comment: "changing color=animal to color=group_name where group_name is whatever you call the Control and Treated groups" is what I did in my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Edit

Here is a solution without using the tidyverse package:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

growth_data <- read.csv("~/Downloads/growth_data.txt", sep = "\t")
growth_data_long <- growth_data %>% pivot_longer(-`animal`, 
                                                 names_to=("Day"),
                                                 values_to=("Growth"))

growth_data_long
#> # A tibble: 60 × 3
#>    animal    Day   Growth
#>    <chr>     <chr>  <dbl>
#>  1 Control 1 Day.1   1.08
#>  2 Control 1 Day.2   1.49
#>  3 Control 1 Day.3   2.73
#>  4 Control 1 Day.4   2.81
#>  5 Control 1 Day.5   3.8 
#>  6 Control 1 Day.6   4.8 
#>  7 Control 2 Day.1   1.22
#>  8 Control 2 Day.2   1.86
#>  9 Control 2 Day.3   2.01
#> 10 Control 2 Day.4   2.53
#> # … with 50 more rows

growth_data_long$group <- gsub(x = growth_data_long$animal, pattern = " \\d+", replacement = "")


ggplot(growth_data_long, aes(x = Day, y = Growth, group = animal, color = group)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-10-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Is there a way to do this with group aesthetics?

Comment: Btw, how does it know which ones are control and which ones are treated?

Comment: I don't believe you can use group in that way (see e.g. https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/aes_group_order.html) and you tell it which ones are Control and which ones are Treated with `mutate(group = str_extract(animal, "\\w+"))`; this is basically saying "create a new variable called "group" and fill it by extracting the first word from every animal (the str_extract part)"

Comment: Is there a way not to do it with extra library `tidyverse`?

Comment: can you check this new question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69459938/how-to-merge-two-dataset-and-plot-them-in-r

Comment: @TinaJ - I have edited my answer to only use ggplot2 and tidyr (i.e. not the tidyverse package)

Answer (score 1):

You can separate your animal column so that you get the label for control or treat.

```
library(tidyr)
growth_data_long <- growth_data_long %>% separate(animal, into = c("group", NA), sep = " ", remove = F)
```

Then produce the graph the same way as before changing `color=animal` to `color=group`.

```
growth_data_long %>% ggplot(aes(Day,Growth, group= animal)) + aes(color=group) +geom_line()+
  geom_point()
```

Comment: I prefer not using a new library

Comment: It's part of tidyverse. Tidyverse is going to be the easiest way to solve this problem.